# Exporting per face texture index from Blender 2.8 with Python

Tags: python, blender

I'm trying to fix my old model exporter from pre 2.8 Blender for the current one.
I've read no more 'uv_textures', so my old function doesn't work:

```
def e_texfaceindex(out,o):   # texture index per face (quad/tri)     
    if len(o.uv_textures) == 0: return
    n = len(o.uv_textures[0].data.values())
    out.write("\ntexindexnum " + str(n) + "\n")

    texarr = [] # textures' names
    for t in bpy.data.images:
        if t.type == 'IMAGE': 
            texarr.append(t.name)

    ni = 0
    for tf in o.uv_textures[0].data.values(): # find texture for every face  
        texindex = 0
        for n in texarr:
            # error, polygon has no texture
            if(tf.image == None): 
                out.write("0 ") #ok?
                break
            else:    
                if(tf.image.name == n):
                    out.write(str(texindex) + " ")
                    break
            texindex = texindex+1            
        ni=ni+1
        if ni==32 : # make new line for every 32 elem
            ni = 0
            out.write("\n")
    out.write("\n")
```

But I can reach material indices with this:

```
def e_materialndices(out,o): # per face mat indices
out.write("\nmaterialindexnum " + str(len(o.polygons)) + "\n")
c = 0
for face in o.polygons:  
    out.write(str(face.material_index) + " ")
    c=c+1
    if(c==32):
        out.write("\n")
out.write("\n")
```

Then this script gave me some hope:

```
import bpy
    ms = bpy.data.materials
    for m in ms:
        for n in m.node_tree.nodes:
            print(n.name)
```

With prints out 'Material output','Principled BSDF','Image Texture'. So I maybe I can find the texture's name of the material with the 'Image Texture' node, but I got stuck here, I don't know how to get it.

Maybe there are way simpler methods for getting per face texture info, any help is appreciated.

Comment: This works:
[code]
def e_texfaceindex(out,o):
    out.write("\ntexindexnum " + str(len(o.polygons)) + "\n")
    c = 0
    for face in o.polygons:  
        mt = bpy.data.materials[face.material_index]    # material for ze poly
        tn = mt.node_tree.nodes.get('Image Texture')    # the magix
        texindex = bpy.data.images.find(tn.image.name)  # the texture index
        if texindex<0: # face has no texture?
            texindex = 0    
        out.write(str(texindex) + " ")
        c=c+1
        if(c==32):
            out.write("\n")
    out.write("\n") </code>